# How to modify the response of as_json in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model called Event, which in turn has_one association with EventType

```
event = Event.last

event.as_json(include: {event_type: {only: :name}}, only: :event_type)
```

This is giving me output

```
{ :event_type=> { "name"=>"Chat" } }
```

But my desired response is

```
{ :event_type => "Chat" }
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You could redefine `as_json` or create your own instance method

Answer (score 0):

You could create an instance method on event and include it in the serialized response, using the `:methods` key (see the documentation for [`as_json`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html#method-i-as_json)).

But you don't want to create an `event_type` method, because the association has_one has created one for you. Maybe you can do `event_method_name`? If you must get exactly the response you wanted, it seems something like JBuilder or Active Model Serializers will give you a better control on the output.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in event.rb.

```
def as_json
  options =  {event_type: event_type[:name]}
  super
end
```

You might also consider creating and calling a new method to avoid overriding the method in case you need the full object elsewhere.

```
def event_type_as_json
  {event_type: event_type[:name]}.as_json
end
```